# How can I run a program from within a different directory in the Linux command line?

Tags: unix

How can I run a program without `cd`'ing to the directory where it resides?

I have tried `./my/dir myfile.pl` and again without the leading `.` but neither work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You enter the full path of the executable:

```
./path/to/my/dir/myfile.pl
```

Comment: The file will still be ran from the directory you are currently in.  keep that in mind.

Answer (score -2):

Two dots solves the problem, one dot generates an error (on debian at least) as in the example below:

../usr/local/bin/myprogram

Comment: Two dots do not 'solve the problem'. The dot refers to the current directory, two dots refer to the parent; they are different paths, one of which may or may not be the one you seek. Depending on the current directory, your example may work, but I believe you're looking for the more general `/usr/local/bin/myprogram`.

Comment: whatever directory  i am in,  one dot 'generates a bash' error!